# Unable to get Oracle database connection, should I format my computer?

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, jdbc

I wanted to connect to an Oracle database using JDBC.

I installed ojdbc6.jar properly and wrote this code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            String id = "study";
            String pass = "1234";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);
            if(con != null) 
                System.out.println("Oracle success");
            else 
                System.out.println("Oracle failed");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, these errors keep occuring; I'm the only among my colleagues with this problem.

```
Error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Undefined Error 
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at ex21jdbc.DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:30)

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Undefined Error
    at ojdbc6/oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:386)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at ojdbc6/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
... 7 more
```

I have tried

1. reinstall jdk-11, oracle, eclipse
2. rename my user folder (no space, no uni-code)

Comment: Although I don't think it'll solve your problem, try a newer version or the Oracle JDBC driver. ojdbc6 means it's for Java 6. Formatting your computer is unlikely to fix this type of problem.

Comment: Reformat your computer?  Would you burn your house down and rebuild it just because you can't find the key to the front door?

Answer (score 0):

Try ojdbc14. I had the same problem with ojdbc6

Download link [ojdbc14](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ojdbc14/ojdbc14.jar.zip)