# Unable to get Oracle database connection,oracle.net.ns.NetException: Undefined Error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I wanted to connect to an Oracle database using JDBC.

I installed ojdbc6.jar properly and wrote this code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.127.129:1521:helowin";
            String id = "msa_checkin";
            String pass = "msa0526";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);
            if(con != null) 
                System.out.println("Oracle success");
            else 
                System.out.println("Oracle failed");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But the output looks like this.

```
Error
java.sql.SQLException: Undefined Error
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.kinth.DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:14)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Undefined Error
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 7 more
```

I search for similar questions,but it doesn't solve my problem.

[Unable to get Oracle database connection, should I format my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920339/unable-to-get-oracle-database-connection-should-i-format-my-computer)

No problem with Navicat.
[Navicat Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIZx6.png)

I tried using oracle6.jar and Oracle14.jar but neither worked.

Comment: Please don't accept link only answers.

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: @tgdavies Why do you suggest using the JDBC driver for Java 1.4 instead of the JDBC driver for Java 6?! The OP should probably use a **newer** driver, not an **older** one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my mistake, I thought that was newer

Comment: This blog post https://expertsys.hu/2019/02/16/oracle-jdbc-connection-problem-undefined-error/ describes one cause a similar error: having the user.name system property set to something with non-ASCII characters. The solution is to pass `-Duser.name=xx` to your program. Your problem may be something quite different, but this is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the instructions on this [page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc-onpremise.html) and try to get a connection using the latest JDBC drivers?